# Distinct function of SQL inside round function

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get distinct values of a column, for eg

```
Select  Isnull(case when x=y then cast((isnull(round(value),0)),0) as int) else 1
```

Here I can't use distinct before case as it returns incorrect value for a logic, I wanted to use distinct before the value is returned . I can't use different select inside cast as per logic

Comment: please provide some sample data and desired output

Comment: Sample data, eg value as 1,2,3,4,5,2. I wanted to a single value 2 as its duplicate

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How can `case` expression depend on repeating rows since it operates only with values of the current row? It is not clear. What about the requirement: you may use subquery in `from` with `distinct` applied.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE(NUM)AS
(
   SELECT 1 UNION ALL
   SELECT 2 UNION ALL
   SELECT 3 UNION ALL
   SELECT 4 UNION ALL
   SELECT 5 UNION ALL
   SELECT 2
)
SELECT C.NUM
FROM CTE AS C
GROUP BY C.NUM
HAVING COUNT(NUM)>1
```